# unfortunately app has stopped afterlogin in android application

Tags: java, android, json, android-intent, android-activity

Json in logcat

```
{
    "tag": "login",
    "success": 1,
    "error": 0,
    "user": {
        "fname": "xxxx",
        "lname": "xxxx",
        "email": "xxxx@xxxx",
        "uname": "xxxx",
        "uid": "565bed3f9ac1e9.89543033",
        "created_at": "2015-11-30 06:31:27"
    }
}
```

But there are not reflecting on gui page(By click on login->(after login)). and I am getting error message like

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value < br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.
```

Here is the login code of my application

```
public class Login extends Activity {

Button btnLogin;
Button Btnregister;
Button passreset;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
private TextView loginErrorMsg;
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
    Btnregister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerbtn);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    passreset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.passres);
    loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginErrorMsg);

    passreset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PasswordReset.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    finish();
    }});


    Btnregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Register.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            finish();
         }});

      /**
    * Login button click event
   * A Toast is set to alert when the Email and Password field is empty
   **/
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (  ( !inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) )
            {
                NetAsync(view);
            }
            else if ( ( !inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) )
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Password field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if ( ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) )
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Email field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Email and Password field are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}


     /**
    * Async Task to check whether internet connection is working.
     **/

private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>
{
    private ProgressDialog nDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
        nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        nDialog.setCancelable(true);
        nDialog.show();
    }
    /**
     * Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by trying Google.
    **/
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){



        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                urlc.connect();
                if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){

        if(th == true){
            nDialog.dismiss();
            new ProcessLogin().execute();
        }
        else{
            nDialog.dismiss();
            loginErrorMsg.setText("Error in Network Connection");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Async Task to get and send data to My Sql database through JSON respone.
 **/
private class ProcessLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {


    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    String email,password;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
        email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
        password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        try {
           if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                    pDialog.setMessage("Loading User Space");
                    pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");
                    /**
                     * Clear all previous data in SQlite database.
                     **/
                    UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                    logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                   /**
                    *If JSON array details are stored in SQlite it launches the User Panel.
                    **/
                    Intent upanel = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
                    upanel.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    startActivity(upanel);
                    /**
                     * Close Login Screen
                     **/
                    finish();
                }else{

                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
}
public void NetAsync(View view){
    new NetCheck().execute();
}
```

}

Registered.java

```
   public class Registered extends Activity {



/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.registered);


    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    user = db.getUserDetails();

    /**
     * Displays the registration details in Text view
     **/

    final TextView fname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fname);
    final TextView lname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lname);
    final TextView uname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uname);
    final TextView email = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
    final TextView created_at = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.regat);
    fname.setText(user.get("fname"));
    lname.setText(user.get("lname"));
    uname.setText(user.get("uname"));
    email.setText(user.get("email"));
    created_at.setText(user.get("created_at"));






    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Login.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            finish();
        }

    });


}}
```

registered.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@drawable/android">

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Congratulations. You have Sucessfully Registered..."
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Your Registration Details"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="First Name"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/fname"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Last Name"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fname"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/lname"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="E-mail"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fname"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/uname"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/email"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/email"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Registered at"
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/uname"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/regat"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lname"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

<Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back to Login"
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lname"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
```

activity_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@drawable/android">
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome to ITC"
        android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
<EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint="E-mail"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

<Button
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/registerbtn"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
<Button
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Register"
        android:id="@+id/registerbtn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pword"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/login"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/loginErrorMsg"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passres"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Email"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/email"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

<EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/pword"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/email"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/email"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Password"
        android:id="@+id/pworda"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pword"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Forgot Password"
        android:id="@+id/passres"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

Comment: provide you parsing code please

Comment: you are getting <br in your response, check it carefully

Comment: look this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997514/value-br-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111640/value-br-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject-on-android

Comment: @ Fabin Paul,@Nilesh i had provided the code please have a look

Comment: @ Ravi Rupareliya how can i remove it?

Answer (score 0):

resolved by adding

json = json.substring(json.indexOf("{"));

the problem is

Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value `< br` of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject